# Finding when the determinant is zero

Tags: matrices

Suppose (x;y; z) is a linear combination of (2;3;1) and (1;2;3). What determinant
is zero? What equation does this give for the plane of all combinations?

Can someone give me a hint or show me how can I solve this, please?

EDIT

I used the determinant

row1 = x y z
row2 = 3 2 1
row3 = 1 2 3

and I reached the equation 4x-8y+4z

I don't know if it's correct or if it's supposed to equal zero and how....

Comment: @Justpassingby gave a pretty clear hint and partial answer. Isn't it clear that the determinant is "supposed to equal zero"? If you do not understand why, you should not be doing these kinds of problems. It looks like you need to review the ideas leading up to your current topic.

Answer (score 2):

The condition that $(x;y;z)$ be linearly dependent on the two given vectors is equivalent to

$$\left|
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3 \\
2&3&1 \\
x&y&z
\end{matrix}
\right|=0.$$